# Flutter and Dart's Red Screen of Death isn't allowing me to Run the App

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, dart

[image: Red Screen Of Death]
I don't know how to fix this and I want to fix this. I am also hoping if I could bypass this, and if so where?

Comment: Post your code instead of this screen

Comment: I have a lot of code so I don't know how do I put that..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: How do I do this? I have a lot of code, so I don't know how to upload all of the code.

Comment: Try wrapping your root widget in with MaterialApp or paste the console error code

Answer (score 1):

You are using the value of `MediaQuery.of(context).size` (I'm taking `size` for example) before the widget is binded to the widget tree, maybe in the initState() function of a StatefulWidget. So the current widget cannot traverse up to find the `MediaQuery` object, hence the error.

The right place to assign value of `MediaQuery.of(context)` would be in the `didChangeDependencies()` or `build()` method. Make sure your app is inside a MaterialApp widget as well.